# connection refused at 127.0.1.1 java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I am new at Java RMI technology. I have a problem that already other programmers had, but I was not able to understand what they did in the tutorials in order to solve it. 
I have implemented the game "tic tac toe" with Java RMI. 
Here the ControllerServer code

```
public ControllerServer() {

    try {
        game = new GameImpl();
        BoardView view = new BoardView(this);
        viewUpdater = new ServerViewUpdaterImpl(view);

        Game gameStub = (Game) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(game, 1099);
        ServerViewUpdater serverViewStub = (ServerViewUpdater) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(viewUpdater, 1099);

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

        registry.rebind("TTTGame", gameStub);
        registry.rebind("TTTServerView", serverViewStub);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here the ControllerClient

```
public ControllerClient() {
    try {

        BoardView view = new BoardView(this);
        localView = new ClientViewUpdaterImpl(view);

        String address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert server's address: ");

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(address, 1099);

        game = (Game) registry.lookup("TTTGame");
        remoteView = (ServerViewUpdater) registry.lookup("TTTServerView");
        remoteView.registerClientView(localView);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It works locally, by inserting "localhost" "127.0.0.1" or my external network IP.
It does not work if client and server run on different machines.

I got the exception "**connection refused by 127.0.1.1**". I do not understand why they are trying to use a localhost address at some point of the execution.

Comment: Are you getting the exception on the lookup, or when executing your remote method?

Comment: on the lookup.
Practically, it gets the registry on the localhost, instead of the registry reachable at the address of the server. Then the lookup executes. Since it does find any registry in the localhost (of course, the registry is on the server!) it goes in exception.

Comment: There's something wrong here. It will only lookup a registry on the localhost if you supply the localhost's IP address to `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()`. If you supply the server's IP address, it will look up the server's Registry. If the exception says 'connection refused by 127.0.1.1', that is *prima facie* evidence you supplied 127.0.1.1 to `LocateRegistry.getRegistry().` Or else you got it on the call not the lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the other said, this is beach your IP is set to **127.0.1.1**

Run a `ipconfig -a` to see what's the IP address of your host.

Then edit the `/etc/hosts` file and instead of this line
    **`127.0.1.1 "name of the host"`**
replace the **127.0.1.1 with the IP of your machine**.

This should work.

You can always validate the IP that the *rmi server* is listening to, by executing:

```
String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
Log.info("this host IP is " + hostname);
```

If you overwrite the `/etc/hosts` file with the correct IP, then everything should work.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your the IP is most likely wrong. It is `127.0.0.1` and not `127.0.1.1`. You can try it with `localhost` as well.

Comment: It is 127.0.1.1, it is localhost as well.

Comment: @user1384636 But the Registry you want isn't in the local host. It is in the server host.

Comment: yes, it is! but I am wondering why does it try to connect to the localhost when I ask explicitly to connect to the server?

Answer (score 2):

You got the address wrong when you called getRegistry(). You need to supply the address of the server host. There is normally no RMI Registry running in a client host.